# Ansible command line retriving ssh password from vault

Tags: ansible

I am trying to setup Ansible to manage Linux boxes from different customers and here are what we have to work with.

1. No Pub key authentication - I wanted it as much as you do but it
   won't happen any time soon.
2. We login as root and each customer has a different root password for all linux boxes. We are pushing for disable direct root login and do everything via `sudo` but again, it will take some time.

I managed to create a ansible vault file for each customer with `ansible_ssh_user` and `ansible_ssh_pass` in it and following play-book works fine.

```
---
- hosts:
    - SERV01
    - SERV02
  vars_files:
    - roles/common/vault/main.yml

  tasks:
    - name: enable and start ntpd
      service: name=ntpd enabled=yes state=running
```

Now I would like to know how can I use vault files from command line, but none of the following worked.

```
ansible customer1 -m shell -a "var_files:roles/common/vault/main.yml uptime" --ask-vault-pass

ansible customer1 -m shell -a "uptime" -e "vars_files:roles/common/vault/main.yml"  --ask-vault-pass
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: `ansible` and `ansible-playbook` are different tools and do not have the same options. I don't see any `-e` in `ansible`.

Comment: I don't agree that ansible and ansible-playbook are different and are you running latest Ansible ? I am using 1.9.0.1 and here is the option `-e EXTRA_VARS, --extra-vars=EXTRA_VARS
                        set additional variables as key=value or YAML/JSON`

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I was running an older version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I found out how to do this:

`ansible customer1 -e @group_vars/vault/customer1.yml --ask-vault-pass -m shell -a uptime`

Now I can put `ansible_ssh_user`, `ansible_ssh_pass` and `ansible_sudo_pass` in a vault file and all I need to remember is the vault password.

I hope that makes Ansible more enjoyable for you as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I want to share my own answer for this even though OP answered it himself. There are a few things I did not find clear by OPs answer:

The solution OP is using is called "group_vars". To use "group_vars" you need to have a "group_vars" directory where your inventory.ini file is located. Inside of the directory create an .yaml file for EACH group name (the object in your inventory.ini that shows `[groupname]`). So if you have the following in your inventory.ini

```
[g1]
10.10.10.10
[g2]
10.10.11.10
```

If you want to make sperate ssh sessions for each group while using group_vars, you need to create the following files:

```
./group_vars/g1.yaml
./group_vars/g2.yaml
```

Inside of these files you can enter your variables, really any variable. But in the context of the problem of this post you would do the folloing:

./group_vars/g1.yaml

```
ansible_ssh_user: "user1"
ansible_ssh_pass: "MyP4ss"
ansible_become_pass: "MyP4ss"
```

./group_vars/g2.yaml

```
ansible_ssh_user: "user2"
ansible_ssh_pass: "MyP4ssNew"
ansible_become_pass: "MyP4ssNew"
```

Now you can run your ansible playbook without even having to pass an extra variable parameter:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i ./inventory.ini myplaybook.yaml --ask-vault-pass
```

BTW You can use ansible vault in the same way. Create a vault encryption for each of the passwords:

```
ansible-vault encrypt_string 'MyP4ss' --name 'ansible_ssh_pass'
ansible-vault encrypt_string 'MyP4ssNew' --name 'ansible_ssh_pass'
```

You will see something like this:

```
ansible_ssh_pass: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          66636431343633646639343661353330326634336565653430326662303039643634303564316132
          313736323431653749839238373332303861353734393430340a3131336662316161633137343235363465303461613534373439333336306130316531363836323137376632
          6335303031343732300a34363636646334613162643863386435303833373735383830343234626480859048029850329
          3539

ansible_ssh_pass: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          9387295873723633646639343661353330326634336565653430326662303039643634303564316132
          313736323431653749839238373332303861353734393430340a3131336662316161633137343235363465303461613534373439333336306130316531363836323137376632
          6335303031343732300a34363636646334613162643863386435303833373735383830343234626480859048029850329
          4738
```

Be aware when running these commands it will ask you to change your ansible vault password each time. It does not erase old passwords. Just put the same ansible vault password if you want to keep the last one you use. Also "ansible_ssh_pass" is just a reference name, You can change that to whatever you want as long as the cypher is the same. Notice below how I copy and paste it and change the reference name each time.

Now just copy that from the terminal and paste in place of your password variables in each group_var file:

./group_vars/g1.yaml

```
ansible_ssh_user: user1
ansible_ssh_pass: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          66636431343633646639343661353330326634336565653430326662303039643634303564316132
          313736323431653749839238373332303861353734393430340a3131336662316161633137343235363465303461613534373439333336306130316531363836323137376632
          6335303031343732300a34363636646334613162643863386435303833373735383830343234626480859048029850329
          3539
ansible_become_pass: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          66636431343633646639343661353330326634336565653430326662303039643634303564316132
          313736323431653749839238373332303861353734393430340a3131336662316161633137343235363465303461613534373439333336306130316531363836323137376632
          6335303031343732300a34363636646334613162643863386435303833373735383830343234626480859048029850329
          3539
```

./group_vars/g1.yaml

```
ansible_ssh_user: user2
ansible_ssh_pass: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          9387295873723633646639343661353330326634336565653430326662303039643634303564316132
          313736323431653749839238373332303861353734393430340a3131336662316161633137343235363465303461613534373439333336306130316531363836323137376632
          6335303031343732300a34363636646334613162643863386435303833373735383830343234626480859048029850329
          4738
ansible_become_pass: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          9387295873723633646639343661353330326634336565653430326662303039643634303564316132
          313736323431653749839238373332303861353734393430340a3131336662316161633137343235363465303461613534373439333336306130316531363836323137376632
          6335303031343732300a34363636646334613162643863386435303833373735383830343234626480859048029850329
          4738
```

Now you are able to connect to multiple hosts, with different ssh login creds, in an organized way, based of your inventory file.

Also here is documentation on using ansible group_vars:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain whether Ansible can do that. If it can't, one way to do it is

```
ansible customer1 -e "`ansible-vault view roles/common/vault/main.yml | grep ansible_ssh_pass`" -m shell -a uptime
```

Comment: You command works when I use `ansible_ssh_pass=whatever` in the vault file but that will break palybook as `mail.yml` must be stored as a dictionary/hash format for example `ansible_ssh_pass: whatever`.  Your command worked after I did some modification but I think I will open an issue with Ansible team to see if they can add this. Thanks